# Continue to Display Comments During Primary Election Phase

Tags: discussion, feature-request, moderator-election

I think removing the comments entirely removes context from the nomination, of which some could be very important to voters. Instead, it was suggested by Cody Gray that they may be removed for the simplicity of scrolling.

If that is the case, perhaps in the next election simply collapse the comment section when the primary phase begins.

[The related uber-meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222078/comments-on-moderator-nomination-statements-should-be-visible-in-all-stages-of-t) has shown that you can navigate to the Nominations tab to see comments, however, I believe this is a pain to tab over, find the candidate again, read the comments, and go back. A collapsed comment section on primaries would remove the issue of "takes up too much space".

Comment: Related: [Hide all comments by default on election nominations, for clarity and fairness](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337608/hide-all-comments-by-default-on-election-nominations-for-clarity-and-fairness)

Comment: Duplicate on the uber-Meta: [Comments on moderator nomination statements should be visible in all stages of the election](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222078/comments-on-moderator-nomination-statements-should-be-visible-in-all-stages-of-t)

Comment: Dueling duplicates.

Comment: Those who wish to read comments can simply flip between Nomination and Primary tabs.

Comment: @Lundin cross-referencing the randomly sorted primary tab and the sorted-by-newest Nomination tab by hand would be a lot of effort.

Comment: @Haem: There are only 11 candidates. `CTRL`+`F`, type in a candidate username, enter and done.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ surely a good user experience would not require users to do Ctrl + F. Even though we developpers know (should  ?) how to use that, it is still a distraction when you have limited time and attention to devote to read a lot of information.

Comment: Anyone suggesting opening multiple tabs or using CTRL-F is suggesting a workaround, not a solution.

Comment: @ABoschman Which is why they're doing so as comments rather than answers.

Comment: @TylerH: Correct... assuming that these comments are intended to be hidden, and candidates are intended to be listed in random order, and that do so is "for clarity and fairness", we can pretty confidently conclude that no changes will be made as a result of this feature-request. My annoying workaround is just what came to mind. In practice, I actually ended up reviewing the nominations page, jotted down who I wanted to vote for, then went back to the primaries and voted, eliminating the back and forth.

Comment: In my browser, there are three tabs — two of them active.  One is labelled 'nomination' (https://stackoverflow.com/election/11?tab=nomination), one is labelled 'primary' (https://stackoverflow.com/election/11?tab=primary; also https://stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1), and one is labelled 'election' (https://stackoverflow.com/election/11?tab=election) but it doesn't yet show much other than that there are 11 candidates at the moment.  The comments are visible in the nomination tab.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ what if one candidate had a screen name like "odera" or "candi"?

Comment: @ABoschman Yeah because we do thousands of moderator electrions per day so changing this needs to be the primary design focus of SO, right? Not improving the everyday use of the site or something like that...

Comment: I agree that the comments should be there, but the issue of scrolling is a valid one. Let's keep the comments but have them hidden by default so you'd have to click to expand them if you actually want to read them.

Comment: @Lundin it's kind of silly to say that. Can we not have ideas and suggestions now because they're not priority ideas?

Comment: @SterlingArcher Sure, suggest away. When was the last time you saw a user suggestion getting implemented?

Comment: @Lundin that's completely irrelevant and dangerous thinking. Don't silence your ideas on the notion that they *might* not be listened to. Be positive!

Comment: @SterlingArcher It means that with so very few things, if any, getting implemented, we'll have to lower the noise ratio. There's somewhere around 5 to 10 feature requests from users per day. That's for more requests per day than SO implements in 1 year. Last year I believe they implemented roughly 0 user requests. How can I be positive when the owners of the site obviously don't give a crap about the site in general and the community in particular?

Comment: @Lundin unfortunately that's out of the scope of this question. I'm not going to let it stop me from voicing my ideas, and I'm sorry you feel the way you do.